# Why is my compareTo method for this class not returning edges <A,B> and <B,A> as the same thing?

Tags: java, graph

Here(down below) is my `MovieEdge` class; nothing special, it points to 2 `Actor` objects which are the vertices of this edge. Also this is an unweighted and undirected graph but we were required to add a `weight` field even though it will always be initialized to 1 so weight can be ignored in the `compareTo` method.

So in my `graph` class I call on my method `edgeSet` which returns a set of all the edges but it is a set so it should only add unique edges BUT take these 2 edges below

```
Actor a = new Actor("James");
Actor b = new Actor("Dan");
MovieEdge one = new MovieEdge(a, b, 1, "Movie1");
MovieEdge one = new MovieEdge(b, a, 1, "Movie1");
```

My compareTo method should output 0 when comparing the 2 MovieEdges above because this is an undirected graph but when I call the following in my main method

```
    testGraph.addEdge(A, C, 1, "Movie1");
    testGraph.addEdge(B, C, 1, "Movie1");
    testGraph.addEdge(C, D, 1, "Movie3");
    testGraph.addEdge(D, A, 1, "Movie1");
    testGraph.addEdge(A, D, 1, "Movie1");
    testGraph.addEdge(A, E, 1, "Movie1");
    System.out.println(testGraph.edgeSet());
```

in my main method this is the output

`[A via Movie1 to C, A via Movie1 to D, A via Movie1 to E, B via Movie1 to C, C via Movie1 to A, E via Movie1 to A, C via Movie3 to D]`

notice how the set displays both 
`A via Movie1 to E` and `E via Movie1 to A`
that is not right

I have been changing my 'compareTo' for since 2am (it's 7:43  am now) but i do not understand, my first 2 conditions that return 0 should take care of this problem but for some reason it is not.

Also I should point out that oddly when I add only a single edge like `testGraph.addEdge(A, E, 1, "Movie1");` and call `System.out.println(testGraph.edgeSet());` it prints correctly and only `[A via Movie1 to E]` prints on the console.

```
public class MovieEdge implements Comparable {

    private Actor source;
    private Actor destination;
    private int weight;
    private String movieName;

    public MovieEdge(Actor source, Actor destination, int wieght, String movieName){
        this.source = source;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.movieName = movieName;
    }

    public Actor getSource() {
        return source;
    }

    public Actor getDestination() {
        return destination;
    }

    public int getWeight(){
        return weight;
    }

    public String getMovieName() {
        return movieName;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return source + " via " + movieName + " to " + destination ;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        MovieEdge a = (MovieEdge)o;
        if(this.movieName.equals(a.movieName)){
            if(this.source.getName().equals(a.source.getName()) && this.destination.getName().equals(a.destination.getName())){
                return 0;
            }
            else if(this.source.getName().equals(a.destination.getName()) && this.destination.getName().equals(a.source.getName())){
                return 0;
            }
            else if(this.destination.compareTo(a.destination) != 0 || this.source.compareTo(a.source) !=0 ){
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
        if(this.movieName.compareTo(a.movieName) < 0){
            return -1;
        }else if(this.movieName.compareTo(a.movieName) > 0){
            return 1;
        }


        return -1;
    }

}
```

my edgeSet Method

```
public Set<MovieEdge> edgeSet() {
    Set<MovieEdge> values = new TreeSet<MovieEdge>();

    for (TreeSet<MovieEdge> value : adjList.values()) {
        for(MovieEdge m : value){
            values.add(m);
        }
    }

    return values;
}
```

`adjList.values()` is just each TreeSet of type MovieEdge for each actor vertex

My graph passes all my instructors JUNIT test so I am getting an A on this assignment but this bug is a personal thing, I MUST KNOW WTF IS WRONG. It is driving me nuts. Thank you.

My updated and still not working (giving me same problem as above) code for the MovieEdge class

```
`@Override 
public int hashCode(){
    return source.getName().hashCode() + destination.getName().hashCode();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj){
    MovieEdge a = (MovieEdge)obj;
    if((source.getName().equals(a.source.getName())) && (destination.getName().equals(a.destination.getName()))){
        return true;
    }
    if((source.getName().equals(a.destination.getName())) && (destination.getName().equals(a.source.getName()))){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    MovieEdge a = (MovieEdge)o;

    if(movieName.equals(a.movieName)){
        if(equals(a))
            return 0;
        else if(source.getName().compareTo(a.source.getName()) < 0)
            return -1;
        else
            return 1;
    }else if(movieName.compareTo(a.movieName) < 0)
        return -1;

    return 1;
}    `
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have two errors in your code:

First, you implement a `Comparable`, but do not override the `equals()` method.
From the [Comparable documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

> It is strongly recommended (though not required) that natural
>   orderings be consistent with equals. This is so because sorted sets
>   (and sorted maps) without explicit comparators behave "strangely" when
>   they are used with elements (or keys) whose natural ordering is
>   inconsistent with equals. In particular, such a sorted set (or sorted
>   map) violates the general contract for set (or map), which is defined
>   in terms of the equals method.

Second your Comparable has a weird behaviour if `movieName` are equal but not the `source` and `destination`, because it always returns `1`. This breaks the [compareTo contract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-):

> (x.compareTo(y)>0 && y.compareTo(z)>0) implies x.compareTo(z)>0

This leads to your `TreeSet` not working properly and thus your edge been added twice.

---

**Edit:** As far as I can see, there is no trivial implementation of the `compareTo` method. So I'd suggest using a `HashSet` with a convenient `hashCode` and `equals` method. Sth. like this:

```
@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + Objects.hashCode(movieName);
    result *= prime;
    // Only add, because order independent
    result += Objects.hashCode(destination);
    result += Objects.hashCode(source);
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj)
{
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    MovieEdge other = (MovieEdge)obj;
    if (Objects.equals(movieName, other.movieName))
    {
        if (Objects.equals(source, other.source)
                && Objects.equals(destination, other.destination))
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (Objects.equals(source, other.destination)
                && Objects.equals(destination, other.source))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @Lumnitz thank you and that looks like it would work but I have not tested it. Unfortunately I will have to stick to my method because I cannot use code that is not mine but regardless thank you. At least I will not have this problem with personal project but with school I can only use my own code.

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by Lumnitz is correct, I just wanted to add below points:

`Set` eliminates duplicates by validating the objects equality using `equals(Object obj)` method, which you did not override for your `MovieEdge` class.

Basically, you need to know the below points:

(1) Override `equals()` and `hashcode()` (from `java.lang.Object`) **for checking objects equality** (your case is this i.e., you wanted to eliminate two `MovieEdge` objects by checking  some conditions using `moviename`, etc..)

> public boolean equals(Object obj) : Indicates whether some other object
>   is "equal to" this one.

(2) Override `compareTo(Object o)` (from `java.lang.Comparable`) **for ordering**  (ascending/ descending) the objects

> public interface Comparable : This interface imposes a total ordering
>   on the objects of each class that implements it

Comment: @ javaguy Thank you for the answer. I read the Comparable documentation that Lumnitz linked and gained some insight. Regardless it did not help me. I went ahead and override the `equals` method for `MovieEdge` and rewrote my `compareTo` method and yet, when I print the set out I still get duplicates. But when I compare or use the `equals` method for all the `MovieEdge` objects individually to their equal (but flipped vertices) `MovieEdge` counterparts I get the expected results, (true and 0).

Comment: could I also point out something that confuses me? When I use a LinkedHashSet instead of a TreeSet even more duplicates get printed out! Should all Set classes use the same adding method to avoid duplicates? If so I find it odd that they do not add the same.